# Why are my buttons differently sized and their contents differently aligned?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Check this example using Bootstrap 4 and Material icons :

[image]

It seems that only the first button is correctly sized and its icon correctly aligned, plus the icons are all the same size.

I noticed that removing the following css code fixes it :

```
.btn-icon::after{
  content: " "  attr(title);
  letter-spacing: -1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
.btn-icon:hover::after{
    letter-spacing: normal;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But I need that effect. Why is this extra "ghost padding" being added on the right of the non-first buttons? And how can I fix this?

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/136541/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so my previous answer had some strong points, but it wasn't correct.
I now have the correct answer for you. It's in the differences;

Your original jsFiddle;

```
 <button title="Button1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon">
          <i class="material-icons">file_download</i></button> <!-- note the 0 space between button and i elements -->
        <button title="Button2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i><!-- What's this? -->
        </button>
        <button title="Button3" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon">
          <i class="material-icons">filter_list</i><!-- what's this? -->
        </button>
```

This is because we are working with inline elements here. We are nesting something within the `button` elemenent, which means it behaves differently. In fact, it behaves differently in the sense that (and browsers don't all treat this the same, ie; Firefox creates spaces and Chrome does not) when you leave empty space within said elements. Usually you wouldn't notice, but because the `:after` creates content behind it, the whitespace is ineed rendered as whitespace (in firefox)

So, there are 2 ways to fix this issue;

**The simple way; remove the whitespace from your code**

```
<button title="Button1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon">
  <i class="material-icons">file_download</i></button>
```

**Or the code-technically messy way but won't break if someone reformats your code so it's more stable and trustworthy way;**

```
<button title="Button1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon"><i class="material-icons">
  file_download
  </i><!-- These comments remove the effective html whitespace!!
 --></button>
<button title="Button2" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon">
  <i class="material-icons">search</i><!-- Because you are commenting them out!
--></button>
<button title="Button3" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon">
  <i class="material-icons">filter_list</i><!-- Amazing, isn't it?!
--></button>
```

This is why I prefer to use `div` elements and just style them as buttons, but that faces different issues. I just avoid these inline elements mostly because they get treated differently cross-browser a lot.

-- oh, and the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/137212/) of course!

[Here is some more info](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) on dealing with `inline-block` elements and their whitespaces!

Comment: The problem still shows for me in firefox, and that space had a purpose

Comment: Well that's odd. Is replacing the space with a padding a possible solution? Anyway, I'm going to check it out on firefox.

Comment: Check out my updated JSfiddle link. Works for me in firefox now. I'll update my answer with the explanation

Comment: I thank you for your time. but now that content when not hovering is blank, it no longer has a smooth animation when you "unhover" it.

Comment: @Mojimi there ya go. The problem was within the HTML and not the CSS. This means you did good and I'm proud of you, newbie. Clearly, even I didn't notice it the first 2-3 looks so, there's that... (I've been doing this for about 5 years). I hope you (and I) can learn something from this!

Comment: I had no idea white spaces were considered in html, thank you for your time and kind words

Comment: Only within certain elements like A, P and buttons (which do not allow divs inside)